# Is there any difference between partially moved values and moved values in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

Currently in Rust master (0.10-pre), when you move one element of a unique vector and try to move a different element, the compiler complains:

```
let x = ~[~1, ~2, ~3];
let z0 = x[0];
let z1 = x[1]; // error: use of partially moved value: `x`
```

This error message is somewhat different from if you were to move the entire vector:

```
let y = ~[~1, ~2, ~3];
let y1 = y;
let y2 = y; // error: use of moved value `y`
```

Why the different message? If `x` is only "partially moved" in the first example, is there any way to "partially move" different parts of `x`? If not, why not just say that `x` is moved?

Comment: Even if there is no way to partially move elements, it would still make sense to have a different error message because moving an element isn't the same as moving the entire vector. It never hurts to have accurate error messages.

Answer (score 2):

> If x is only "partially moved" in the first example, is there any way
>   to "partially move" different parts of x?

Yes, there is, but only when you move these parts all at once:

```rust
let x = ~[~1, ~2, ~3];
match x {
    [x1, x2, x3] => println!("{} {} {}", *x1, *x2, *x3),
    _ => unreachable!()
}
```

It can be easily observed that `xN`s are really moved out because if you add additional line after the match:

```rust
println!("{:?}", x);
```

The compiler will throw an error:

```
main3.rs:16:22: 16:23 error: use of partially moved value: `x`
main3.rs:16     println!("{:?}", x);
                                 ^
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std-macros>:195:27: 195:81 note: expansion site
<std-macros>:194:5: 196:6 note: in expansion of println!
main3.rs:16:5: 16:25 note: expansion site
main3.rs:13:10: 13:12 note: `(*x)[]` moved here because it has type `~int`, which is moved by default (use `ref` to override)
main3.rs:13         [x1, x2, x3] => println!("{} {} {}", *x1, *x2, *x3),
                     ^~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

This is also true for structures and enums - they also can be partially moved.